# How to filter List of Object with multiple filters

Tags: java, arrays, filter

I have a requirement where I have to filter the `List<Objects>` with multiple filter values in a single flow. Suppose:

```
Class abc{
String name;
String lastName;
String middleName;
}
```

and filter values like `firstName == Abhishek` or `firstName == rajesh` or `firstName == deepak`.

What is the best way to filter this. One more thing, if I have applied filter on `firstName` and filtered list is returned and again if I want to apply filter on `lastName` than both the filter should work like with existing filter on `firstName` additional filter should be applied on `lastName`

Answer (score 0):

```
List<abc> finalList = new ArrayList<abc>();
for(abc singleElement:abcList){
    if(singleElement.getFirstName.equals("Abhishek")){
        finalList.add(singleElement);
    }
}
```

finalList is the filtered list now.
You can apply similar filter for lastName on the finalList.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void filter(ArrayList<abc> testing, String filterWord) {
    for (abc elem : testing) {
        if (elem.name.equals(filterWord))
            testing.remove(elem);
        if (elem.lastName.equals(filterWord))
            testing.remove(elem);
        if (elem.middleName.equals(filterWord))
            testing.remove(elem);
    }
```